# Changing the textcolor application wide dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, skinning

I want to change the text color (foreground) of all controls in the application at once dynamically during runtime. Is there a recommended way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to define all possible themes at design in separate files. Then change the theme at runtime which will eventually change the foreground color of controls.

See [this simple post](http://blog.xamltemplates.net/?p=20) it explains how you can change themes at runtime.

```
//declare a resource dictionary
ResourceDictionary skin = new ResourceDictionary();
//load your theme
skin.Source = new Uri(@”ThemeName.xaml”, UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
//apply it
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(skin);
```

If you want to know more about themes go to [this page](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes). It has 9 sample themes which you can download and see how themes are created

Answer (score 0):

Make use of styles, resources, resource dictionaries and apply them at runtime.

Here's a good article on how you can do this:

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/22/simple-skinnable-and-theme-management-in-wpf-user-interface/